# Not closing OutputStream file when not exiting App properly

Tags: ios, swift

For example:
If an OutputStream to file is closed when the App goes to background, and (for example) running from Xcode, or if the App crashes and the OutputStream never gets closed.

Any possible leaks? Dose the process gets terminated when the run loop gets terminated?

In other words, can not closing an OutputStream cause a system leak beyond the App life scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referencing a `NSOutputStream` or its family of `NSStream`s.

Why would you have a "leak" or even care about a leak if your app was killed? Streams are like file handles and are associated with your process. Regarding the app going to background, the stream could become stale but you should get a message `streamError` to your delegate

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
```

You can check the documentation here
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html

Comment: Thanks! And yes, `OutputStream` is the Swift equivalent of Obj-C's `NSOutputStream`. The documentation did not mention the consequences of not closing a stream.